# Structured Data Testing error, the value provided for logo.url must be a valid URL

Tags: url, web, structured-data

I'm getting this error with tructured Data Testing Tool and have yet to figure out how to fix it , should i add my url before wp-content ??

[image: Structured Data Testing error]

Comment: Please include a minimal example that  gives this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing this is an article-based script, so try this setup (add commas after last } if needed).

PS! Logo height cannot be more than 60px, and by removing the "" after height/width you lose the "Intangible" `@type` feedback from validator.

```
"logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "logo url (jpg/png picture prefered)",
        "height": 60, 
        "width": 150 }

"image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "image url",
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 800 }
```